# Translation prevention mechanism does not work

Tags: microsoft-translator

As an example, I'd like to translate "Overview of Azure Machines" to "de", where "Azure Machines" shouldn't be translated, but there are several issues with it.

This is [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Translator/prevent-translation) I am relating to.

Escaping single words via `@` or `#` works.

Not translating a sentence or parts of a sentence does not:

```
Input (plain): Overview of <span class="notranslate">Azure Machines</span>
Output       : Übersicht über die Option "span class="notranslate">Azure Machines</span>
Issue        : Opening angle bracket removed

Input (HTML) : Overview of <span class="notranslate">Azure Machines</span>
Output       : --- This is the only combination that works but not documented. ---
Issue        : --- This is the only combination that works but not documented. ---

Input (plain): Overview of <div class="notranslate">Azure Machines</div>
Output       : Übersicht über die Datei »div class="notranslate">Azure Machines</div>
Issue        : Opening angle bracket replaced

Input (HTML) : Overview of <div class="notranslate">Azure Machines</div>
Output       : Übersicht über<div class="notranslate">Azure Machines</div>
Issue        : Space before opening angle bracket removed
```

**NOTE:** The docs have been [updated](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commit/d4d0bcbed5a21339b444b98a0d6cbb9b64b0eda5#diff-94e1b226dd4bb32c82c1e0aa4f4b28f4) and now saying that the `class="notranslate"` scenario works for HTML only (so the `Input (plain)` examples are now out of scope here).

The following questions remain to me though:

- Why is the space being removed in the last example? This basically makes it a blocker for us.
- Is `class="notranslate"` working on every HTML tag? For example if I have a table `<table class="notranslate">...</table>`. If so, this should be reflected in the documentation accordingly.
- I suppose the dynamic dictionary syntax (`<mstrans:dictionary translation="translation of phrase">phrase</mstrans:dictionary>`) is supported in `textType: plain` mode, why is this not the case for `<something class="notranslate">phrase</something>`?

For those "no-translate" scenarios I would not want to use the dictionary syntax because it would lead to a drastically increased character count and hence, increased costs.

*And just a side note which has nothing to do with the question: Naming it "Twitter tag" is really weird. It has nothing to do with Twitter. These are simply two possible escaping prefix characters.*

Comment: If you have a lot of dictionary terms that you want to translate in a specific way, you could look at training a custom model. Then you don't need to mark each phrase in the input https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/customization/

Comment: Unfortunately this is no option for us. Besides the initial cost to train the model, the pricing of translations is also 4 times higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation clearly states this only works in html mode. You need to use the no-translate tag to not translate part of the sentence.

Only div and span are supported, not all html tags. Also you should not repeat the content you want to be not translated outside of the no-translate tag. 
For your example, span preserves the space.

`Overview of <span class="notranslate">Azure Machines</span>`

`Übersicht über <span class=\"notranslate\">Azure Machines</span>`

> It's by design that this works only when the input textType is set as
>   HTML

Comment: Yes, the documentation clearly states this [since 2 days now](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commit/d4d0bcbed5a21339b444b98a0d6cbb9b64b0eda5#diff-94e1b226dd4bb32c82c1e0aa4f4b28f4), thank you. But there are still some things unclear to me, I will update my question.

Comment: You may want to edit your answer afterwards to integrate additions to my edits then. After that I would be happy to mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: So you‘re saying that if „Azure Machines“ would be mentioned multiple times, I only have to wrap it in the no translate span a single time?

Comment: no the opposite. It should be wrapped each time you want it to not be translated. In your example it looks like it appears not wrapped, and also wrapped, which will be translated differently. If you train a custom model, then your phrasefix file can take care of your terms without having to wrap each one.

Comment: Ahhh, now I see what you‘re aiming at. Thanks, this was just a typo! :)

Comment: Do you know though why div swallows the space? Is this a bug?